# Gatsby data from external markdown file

Tags: javascript, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I have searched but cant find what i'm looking for.

Is it possible to have .md file externally hosted (say in an S3 bucket) and query those files in Gatsby to populate a template or do they have to be local .md file to do that like the Gatsby docs suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default (without using any [custom source plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-a-source-plugin/)), when dealing with markdown files you need to treat them locally. This is because Gatsby markdown files are set in [Gatsby's filesystem](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/) to create queryable GraphQL nodes (`markdownRemark`) and those nodes are internal files.

Of course, as many plugins do, you can create nodes from outer sources like any external CMS (like Contentful, DatoCMS, etc) but in this case, you will need to create a custom implementation to get the data and parse the data from the external markdown file.

In your case, I think the better approach is to expose a [GraphQL API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-graphql/)/URL in the server to retrieve the data as JSON rather than a markdown file to create custom nodes from it.

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a go